# First step in java.nio

Tags: java, buffer, java.nio.file

I'm moving the first steps in java and I met this kind of package.

Why was the package java.nio introduced and what does'nio' stand for?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+java+nio

Answer (score 0):

NIO stands for *non-blocking input/output* or *new input/output*.

It was first introduced in Java 1.4, but it has been updated in new versions of Java. Main difference from classic Java IO are:

1. in NIO you are using *Channels* and *Buffers* instead of byte and character *Streams*
2. NIO is **non-blocking**, which means that thread can do something else while channel is reading data
3. NIO provides *selectors* used for monitoring multiple channels for events at once